# I have a number and the percentage this number represents - how do I calculate what the full value is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have two known values : A sum and a percentage.

I know that the sum is $16 000$, and this is $28\%$ of unknown value.
How do I calculate what this value is? Like; $16000$ is $28\%$ of $x$?

Doing $16000 \cdot 1.28$ gives me $20480$. But that's wrong?

Comment: A sum requires two addends, but you seem to be referring to only one number.  Are you sure you have your terms right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let our unknown quantity be $q$. Then $28\%$ of $q$ is $16000$.
In symbols,
$$(0.28)q=16000.$$
Divide both sides of the above equation by $0.28$. We get
$$q=\frac{16000}{0.28}.$$
Now it is probably best to use a calculator. We get $q\approx 57142.86$.

If you prefer, you can think of $28\%$ as $28$ "per centum," meaning out of $100$. So $28\%$ means $\frac{28}{100}$.
Thus we could write our equation as
$$\frac{28}{100}q=16000.$$
Multiply both sides by $100$, and then divide both sides by $28$. We get
$$q=\frac{16000\times 100}{28}.$$

**Remark:** It is always possible to make mistakes in this sort of calculation, a little slip in algebra, or a calculator keying error. So it is a very good idea to **check** whether the number you obtained is right. In this case, we do that by finding $28\%$ of our supposed answer of $57142.86$.

**Added:** OP has indicated that the real problem is as follows. Tax is $28\%$. a project pays $16000$ **after tax**. What is the **before tax** income from the project?

Let $b$ be the before tax income. Then $b$ **minus** $28\%$ of $b$ is $16000$. That means that $72\%$ of $b$ is $16000$. Using exactly the same reasoning as before, we have 
$$(0.72)b=16000.$$
Using exactly the same procedure as before, we conclude that
$$b=\frac{16000}{0.72}.$$
The calculator gives $b\approx 22222.22$. Cute!

Comment: Your answere makes perfectly sense - but I've must have asked totally wrong... 
I have a project which pays 16000 after tax, and I know that the tax is set to 28%. What I needed to find out is how much the salary is before tax... I'm really sorry about that.

Comment: @ThomasK: Yes, that is a quite different problem than the one suggested by your wording. I will leave the answer as is, but add something that solves the new problem. It will take a few minutes, I am not a fast typist, and tend to wordiness.

Comment: Yes, I see that now - when I reread my question. Wasn't by intention at all. Again - I'm really sorry about that... And thanks for your patience...

Comment: No problem. Often in applied problems, the main difficulty is formulating the problem correctly. That can be hard. Frequently, after the problem is formulated correctly, the actual details of the solution are technically routine.

Comment: nice :) thank you so much André...